# UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect' has been replaced by instance method 'CGRect.inset(by:)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4.2

I made the mistake up updating my project to Swift 4.2 without waiting for pods to be updated. I have slowly updated all of my code, but there's one line that I can't seem to figure out.

```
var animationRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(frame, UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding))
```

The error I receive is,

> UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect' has been replaced by instance method
>   'CGRect.inset(by:)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The error it is pretty self explanatory. You can use it like this:

```
var animationRect = frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: padding, left: padding, bottom: padding, right: padding))
```

or simply

```
var animationRect = frame.insetBy(dx: padding, dy: padding)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was sure it was a simple answer, but I'm still new to swift and slowly figuring out syntax.

Answer (score 24):

**Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10**

Earlier it was like this -

```
let bounds = UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(view.bounds,view.safeAreaInsets)
```

Now for swift 4.2 -

```
let bounds = view.bounds.inset(by: view.safeAreaInsets)
```

Comment: This one helps!!

Answer (score 2):

UIEdgeInsets in Swift 4.2

> Earlier version
>
> ```
> let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 5)
>  override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
>             return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
>         }
> ```

```
to swift 4.2 and Xcode 10
```

> ```
> let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 5)
>  override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
>         return rect.inset(by: GlobalClass.language == "ar" ? paddingR : padding)
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -2):

This kind of issues with pods can also be solved by setting `SWIFT_VERSION` for a particular pod.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

    if ['MessageKit'].include? target.name
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '5.0'
      end
    end

  end
end
```